# Output doesnt match when use crontab for awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, awk

I have a script for server monitoring, the script work normal when i run manual use `./monitoring.sh`. But when i run it use crontab, There is an additional output in the **cron_status** variable, which is "awk". But that only happens on the main server (***StorageEng***), servers that are remoted with ssh do not experience that. Here is my script code:

```
#!/bin/bash
## Scipt Monitoring Server
# Konfigurasi SQL
db_user="xx"
db_pass="xxxxx"
db_host="localhost"
db_name="Monitoring"
db_table="server"

# Function Query
query() {
    local_query=$1
    mysql  --local-infile=1 -u "$db_user" -h "$db_host" "$db_name" -p"$db_pass" <<EOF
$local_query
EOF
}

# Konfigurasi penyimpanan csv
#USER=$(who | awk 'NR==1 {print $1}')
USER=$(whoami)
WORKDIR="/home/${USER}/Monitoring"
csv_file="${WORKDIR}/monitoring.csv"

# Mengecek apakah file CSV sudah ada, jika belum maka membuat header kolom
if [ ! -e "$csv_file" ]; then
    echo "server_name,ip_address,cpu_usage,memory_used_mb,memory_capacity_mb,memory_free_mb,memory_shared_mb,memory_cache_mb,memory_available_mb,swap_capacity_mb,swap_used_mb,swap_free_mb,disk_used_gb,disk_free_gb,disk_capacity_gb,total_task,running_task,sleeping_task,stopped_task,rx_rate,tx_rate,total_rate,uptime,active_user,cron_status,date_time" > "$csv_file"
fi

# Menghapus semua data dari baris 2 sampai bawah dari file CSV
sed -i '2,$d' "$csv_file"

# INFOSERVER
server_name=$(hostname | awk '{print $1}')
server_ip=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}' )

## Mengambil Data
# CPU
cpu_usage=$(top -bn1 | awk '/Cpu/ {print $2}')
# MEMORY
memory_used=$(free --mega | awk '/Mem/{print $3}')
memory_capacity=$(free --mega | awk '/Mem/{print $2}')
memory_free=$(free --mega | awk '/Mem/{print $4}')
memory_shared=$(free --mega | awk '/Mem/{print $5}')
memory_cache=$(free --mega | awk '/Mem/{print $6}')
memory_available=$(free --mega | awk '/Mem/{print $7}')
# SWAP 
swap_used=$(free --mega | awk '/Swap/{print $3}')
swap_capacity=$(free --mega | awk '/Swap/{print $2}')
swap_free=$(free --mega | awk '/Swap/{print $4}')
# DISK
disk_used=$(df -h | awk '/mapper/{gsub("G", "", $3); print $3}')
disk_free=$(df -h | awk '/mapper/{gsub("G", "", $4); print $4}')
disk_capacity=$(df -h | awk '/mapper/{gsub("G", "", $2); print $2}')
# PROCESS  
total_task=$(top -bn1 | awk '/Tasks/{print $2}')
running_task=$(top -bn1 | awk '/Tasks/{print $4}')
sleeping_task=$(top -bn1 | awk '/Tasks/{print $6}')
stopped_task=$(top -bn1 | awk '/Tasks/{print $8}')
uptime=$(uptime -p | sed 's/,/;/g')
active_user=$(who | wc -l)
# Network
tx_rate=$(vnstat -5 1 | awk 'FNR == 7 {
    if ($6 ~ /KiB/)
        {
            $5/=976.6;
        }
    else if ($5 ~ /MiB/)
        {
        $5*=1.048567;
        }
        printf("%.2f\n", $5);
    }')
rx_rate=$(vnstat -5 1 | awk 'FNR == 7 {
    if ($3 ~ /KiB/)
        {
            $2/=976.6;
        }
    else if ($3 ~ /MiB/)
        {
        $2*=1.048567;
        }
        printf("%.2f\n", $2);
    }')

 total_rate=$(vnstat -5 1 | awk 'FNR == 7 {
    if ($9 ~ /KiB/)
        {
            $8/=976.6;
        }
    else if ($8 ~ /MiB/)
        {
        $8*=1.048567;
        }
        printf("%.2f\n", $8);
    }')   

# Cron Status
cron_status=$(systemctl status cron | awk '/Active/{print $2}')
# DATETIME
date_time=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Menambahkan data terbaru ke file CSV
echo "$server_name,$server_ip,$cpu_usage,$memory_used,$memory_capacity,$memory_free,$memory_shared,$memory_cache,$memory_available,$swap_capacity,$swap_used,$swap_free,$disk_used,$disk_free,$disk_capacity,$total_task,$running_task,$sleeping_task,$stopped_task,$rx_rate,$tx_rate,$total_rate,$uptime,$active_user,$cron_status,$date_time" >> "$csv_file"

for list in `cat ${WORKDIR}/list_server`
        do
                IPADDRESS=$(echo "${list}" | awk -F',' '{print $2}')
                USER=$(echo "${list}" | awk -F',' '{print $3}')
        ssh $USER@${IPADDRESS} "/usr/bin/bash /home/rizci/Monitoring/monitoring.sh"
        ssh $USER@${IPADDRESS} "cat /home/rizci/Monitoring/monitoring.csv | sed '1d'" >> "$csv_file"
done


query "
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$csv_file'
    INTO TABLE $db_table
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (server_name, ip_address, cpu_usage, memory_used_mb, memory_capacity_mb, memory_free_mb, memory_shared_mb, memory_cache_mb, memory_available_mb, swap_capacity_mb, swap_used_mb, swap_free_mb, disk_used_gb, disk_free_gb, disk_capacity_gb, total_task, running_task, sleeping_task, stopped_task, rx_rate, tx_rate, total_rate, uptime, active_user, cron_status, date_time);
"


# Menampilkan data di layar
echo "Berikut adalah data yang akan di-input:"
echo "Server Name          : $server_name"
echo "Ip Address           : $server_ip"
echo "Cpu Usage (%)        : $cpu_usage"
echo "Memory Used (MB)     : $memory_used"
echo "Memory Capacity (MB) : $memory_capacity"
echo "Memory Free (MB)     : $memory_free"
echo "Memory Shared (MB)   : $memory_shared"
echo "Memory Cache (MB)    : $memory_cache"
echo "Memory Available (MB): $memory_available"
echo "Swap Capacity (MB)   ; $swap_capacity"
echo "Swap Used (MB)       : $swap_used"
echo "Swap Free (MB)       : $swap_free"
echo "Disk Used (GB)       : $disk_used"
echo "Disk Free (GB)       : $disk_free"
echo "Disk Capacity (GB)   : $disk_capacity"
echo "Total Task           : $total_task"
echo "Running Task         : $running_task"
echo "Sleeping Task        : $sleeping_task"
echo "Stopped Task         : $stopped_task"
echo "RX Rate (5 min)      : $rx_rate"
echo "TX Rate (5 min)      : $tx_rate"
echo "Total Rate (5 min)   : $total_rate"
echo "Uptime               : $uptime"
echo "Active User          : $active_user"
echo "Cron Status          : $cron_status"
echo "dateTime             : $date_time"
```

Here is output for monitoring.csv when run manual:

```
server_name,ip_address,cpu_usage,memory_used_mb,memory_capacity_mb,memory_free_mb,memory_shared_mb,memory_cache_mb,memory_available_mb,swap_capacity_mb,swap_used_mb,swap_free_mb,disk_used_gb,disk_free_gb,disk_capacity_gb,total_task,running_task,sleeping_task,stopped_task,rx_rate,tx_rate,total_rate,uptime,active_user,cron_status,date_time
StorageEng,172.xx.xxx.xxx,0.0,919,2017,188,4,909,902,2147,66,2080,8.7,28,39,149,1,146,1,0.22,0.24,0.46,up 1 week; 6 days; 23 hours; 36 minutes,3,active,2023-10-09 11:19:16
ServerTesting,172.xx.xxx.xxx,0.0,355,2017,165,2,1496,1454,2147,8,2139,5.9,31,39,147,1,146,0,0.31,0.01,0.33,up 4 weeks; 3 days; 17 hours; 49 minutes,0,active,2023-10-09 11:19:16
DevOps,172.xx.xxx.xxx,0.0,607,2017,167,2,1242,1209,2147,250,1896,13,24,39,148,1,147,0,0.08,0.09,0.17,up 3 weeks; 4 days; 19 hours; 18 minutes,0,active,2023-10-09 11:19:18
```

And here is the output when use crontab:

```
server_name,ip_address,cpu_usage,memory_used_mb,memory_capacity_mb,memory_free_mb,memory_shared_mb,memory_cache_mb,memory_available_mb,swap_capacity_mb,swap_used_mb,swap_free_mb,disk_used_gb,disk_free_gb,disk_capacity_gb,total_task,running_task,sleeping_task,stopped_task,rx_rate,tx_rate,total_rate,uptime,active_user,cron_status,date_time
StorageEng,172.17.30.182,1.6,922,2017,186,4,909,899,2147,66,2080,8.7,28,39,151,1,147,1,0.31,0.41,0.72,up 1 week; 6 days; 23 hours; 38 minutes,3,active
awk,2023-10-09 11:21:02
ServerTesting,172.17.30.183,0.0,352,2017,168,2,1496,1457,2147,8,2139,5.9,31,39,148,1,147,0,0.41,0.01,0.43,up 4 weeks; 3 days; 17 hours; 50 minutes,0,active,2023-10-09 11:21:03
DevOps,172.17.30.181,0.0,601,2017,172,2,1243,1215,2147,250,1896,13,24,39,148,1,147,0,0.08,0.09,0.16,up 3 weeks; 4 days; 19 hours; 20 minutes,0,active,2023-10-09 11:21:05
```

Here is my crontab -e:

```
  GNU nano 6.2                                                                    /tmp/crontab.SNRQNh/crontab                                                                              
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /home/rizci/Monitoring/monitoring.sh
```

Comment: And what does your crontab-entry look like?

Comment: try saving the entire output (eg. `systemctl status cron | tee /tmp/debug.log | awk ...`) and examine the content

Comment: Your script has a lot of issues, e.g. calling awk 9 times instead of just once at most on the output of `free --mega`, wrong capitalization of variables, unquoted variables, `for` loop antipatterns, etc. so you may want to ask some new question for help on doing the various things you're trying to do but for your current problem - you're probably running bash in the terminal while cron is running sh so add a shebang of `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to the top of your script so it always runs in the same shell.

Comment: Start from https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @EdMorton sorry, i have already put ```#!/bin/bash``` in my top of script but forget to add it on my question

Comment: @tink ```*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /home/rizci/Monitoring/monitoring.sh```

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be related to the locations of the commands used and what PATH's are in use inside cron. Cron calling the script passes a very limited PATH string and the script may not be finding some commands because of this. Most of the commands look very standard and would be part of the usual directories covered by a cron PATH. But 'vnstat' and 'mysql' stands out to me as ones that might not be found.

One way to fix this is to identify what path directories any 'unusual' commands like 'vnstat' have. A way to do that is: `which vnstat`
Knowing the path of utilities like that you can add a `export PATH=$PATH:<whatever path you learned>` to the top of the script.

Another way to handle this is to display your current path in the command line like this: `echo $PATH`

Then take this entire line and add it to the top of the script:
`export PATH=<< The entire Path you saw>>`

Example when seeing the echo:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/some/other/bin
```

In this example, add this to the script: `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/some/other/bin`

This will allow cron to call the script and for the script to set any needed PATH directories so the rest of the script can find the commands.